# in R, how can I find the row number of the first occurrence and last occurrence of a value in a Matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

In R, I've created 25x25 matrices of values of 1 and 0 and I need to find the height between the first occurrence of 1 in the matrix and the last occurrence of 1 in the matrix.
Heres an example of a matrix of the letter a, where each 1 represents a black pixel and each 0 represents a white pixel:

```
    a <- read.csv(csv_files[1]) 
    a
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24 V25
1   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8   0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9   0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
10  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
11  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
12  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
13  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
14  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
15  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
16  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
17  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
18  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
19  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
20  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
21  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
22  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
23  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
24  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
25  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

My idea is the find the row number of the last occurrence of 1 and the row number of the first occurrence of 1 and take them away from eachother, which will give me the height of the symbol.
In this case it would be 19 - 6 = 13, so the height is 13.

For context, I drew images of different letters and symbols on GIMP, and the imported them into R and saved them in a matrix as a CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below

```
> diff(range(which(a == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)[, "row"]))
[1] 13
```

**Data**

```
> dput(a)
structure(list(V1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
    V2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V3 = c(0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L), V6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), V7 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V8 = c(0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V9 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V10 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V11 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L), V12 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), V13 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V14 = c(0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V15 = c(0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V16 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V17 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L), V18 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L), V19 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
    V20 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V21 = c(0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V22 = c(0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V23 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V24 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L), V25 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3",
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25"))
```

Comment: thanks man, that worked perfectly. Could you maybe explain the code "diff(range(which(a == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)[, "row"]))"?

Comment: @Niall `which` with option `arr.ind = TRUE` gives a matrix including the row and column numbers where `a==1` is met. We focus on row numbers, so we apply `[,"row"]` to subset the row numbers. `range` gives the min and max values, and `diff` computes the difference, i.e., height.

Comment: Could it also be applied for the width if I changed [, "row"] to ["col", ]?

Comment: @Niall `"row"` is one column name of the indices matrix. If you want to retrieve data from all rows but the `"row"` column, you should use `[, "row"] `.  `["col", ]` means all data from row `"col"` across all columns. You can try `which` first to see what it produced.